# Unable to store ManyToOne association for an entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am unable to bind foreign_key baz_id to Baz on a POST call, it fails with a instantiation error trying to store a **bar**

```
POST http://localhost/foo/api/v1/bars
{
    "baz_id" : "1",
    "weight" : "1.0"

}

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "baz_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
private Baz baz;
```

Comment: Please give us more information. Which error occurs?

Comment: this isn't a JSON->Database mapping, so sending in "{ "baz_id" : "1" } will not build you a 'Baz' instance for the java object reference. Try serializing your 'bars' instance the other way to look at how it will need to handle building you a bars instance on the back end - but you'll need your own way to deal with a Baz id and decide what you want JPA/persistence to do with it to fill that 'baz_id' fk column, such as manually calling find with that Id value and setting the reference yourself.

Comment: For persistence sake, if baz_id can be stored in the corresponding column that would be awesome. Isn't this a standard feature which you would expect to be supported out of the box. I don't want to handle any other prePersist code which allows me to do a lookup of the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: We need more information, you do not provide the 2 entities that are connected, you do not provide the controller, you do not even provide the stack trace.

Comment: It maybe a standard problem, but it is not something the 3 very different techs involved handle without you telling it how to. JSON->Java entity, where you haven't mapped what a 'baz_id' property is, so it has no idea how to handle it. Then you have JPA to convert your java entity to a relational schema; this knows how to convert a Baz reference into a baz_id column. But you have nothing to tell your JSON converter what to do or how to hook into your JPA mappings; your code will have to take the JSON and do a findById search on the value to read in a Baz instance from JPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is incorrect for the object being mapped. It should be of the form:

```
{
  "baz" : {"id":"1"},
  "weight" : "1.0"
}
```

this will allow Spring to build a bar instance that references a Baz instance with an id of 1.

Alternatively, if you use

```
{
  "baz_id" : "1",
  "weight" : "1.0"
}
```

your java entity will need to define a 'baz_id' property within it:

```
@Transient
private String baz_id;
```

Which your controller then uses to decide how to handle this value; ie using the appropriate findbyId method to set the baz reference before saving your Bar instance - this also gives you the opportunity to validate it does exist and decide what to do if it doesn't; create a new one or throw an appropriate exception.

Alternatively, you can map the String basic to the column, and only use that to set the value:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "baz_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@JsonIgnore
private Baz baz;

@Column(name = "baz_id", nullable = false)
private String baz_id;
```

This will let you use the baz_id for REST api, but the baz reference for joins and other application usage.

Comment: "baz" : {"id":"1"} - using this still throws an error and its unable to map

Comment: {
    "message": "The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!",
    "status": 500,
    "timestamp": "2022-05-10T10:55:33.290978"
}

Comment: Using baz_id, baz will complicate things as you have multiple references to the same object. would want to keep it simple for sure

Comment: the error message is talking about an id - you haven't shown one in your entity. Check the server logs; is this coming from JPA or the JSON conversion, and how do you assign ID values?